# Vb.net WebBrowser NewWindow2 how to do?

Tags: vb.net

i find some information. Microsoft Web Browser can get NewWindow2 like this,

```
Private Sub AxWebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2Event) Handles AxWebBrowser1.NewWindow2
    Dim frmWB As Form1
    frmWB = New Form1()

    frmWB.AxWebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = True
    e.ppDisp = frmWB.AxWebBrowser1.Application
    frmWB.Visible = True
End Sub
```

But i need for WebBrowser. Not Microsoft Web Browser.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

To do this on a normal webbrowser control would be like

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(sender as Object, e as CancelEventArgs) _ 
Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow

'code

End Sub
```

If you needed or wanted to you can also import the Microsoft web browser control and just use it